Transferring UV's-From Simplified to High Poly
I'm currently stuck on a project in Blender, that is I have a high poly mesh and a simplified version of it.
I uv-unwrapped the simplified version of the mesh and tried to transfer the uv's to the high poly one using sample nearest surface and it's working partially but I'm getting some distortion on the seams (from the simplified mesh)
I'm not too sure on what is causing this issue, but I would say that it's an interpolation issue on the faces in regard to the seams.
If anyone has a fix to this issue or another solution to transfer the uv's, please let me know.


Could you provide, using https://blend-exchange.com/, a simplified version of your Blender file containing only the texture to transfer, both levels of mesh (low and high poly), and the GN graph part transferring UV ? Could you also indicate if the high ploy mesh is a subdivision of the low poly mesh (sharing some points and vertices) ?
